# Drawing on JavaFX canvas does nothing

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to draw an oval in a canvas but `fillOval` does nothing.
There are no exceptions or errors. While debugging it seems to get to the code and run it but nothing appears on the screen.

code (only the relevant package): https://github.com/amnon3234/PTM_Project/tree/master/PTM_Project_Final/src/view

specific parts:
My canvas:

```
public class HeightMapDisplayer extends Canvas {

    public HeightMapDisplayer() {
        GraphicsContext gc = this.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(Color.RED);
        gc.fillOval(10,10,40,40);
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
public class MainWindowController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    HeightMapDisplayer _heightMap;

    // Constructor , Initialize data
    public MainWindowController() {
        _heightMap = new HeightMapDisplayer();
    }
}
```

My XML:

```
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="view.MainWindowController">
   <left>
    ...
               <HeightMapDisplayer fx:id="heightMap" height="400.0" width="400.0" />
    ...
</BorderPane>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: This code won't compile. Please [edit] the question with a real, reproducible example. Also, please follow proper naming conventions: it's really difficult to read your code when the syntax highlighter highlights your variable names as class names and your variable names have unnecessary (and non-standard) underscores all over the place.

Comment: the code is part of a larger program, that's why u can't understand the naming,
this is the full code : https://github.com/amnon3234/PTM_Project/tree/master/PTM_Project_Final/src/view

Comment: No-one wants to read your entire project. Create a [mre] that reproduces the problem and post it in the question. The fact that it's part of a larger project is *not* the reason the syntax highlighter thinks your variable names are class names, or the reason your code doesn't compile.

Comment: I sent the specific package it contains only the relevant code to my question

Comment: @James_D Thanks btw for trying (not sarcastic)

Comment: The problem is that you implicitly call the `Canvas` default constructor, which sets the width and height to zero, then you do the drawing, *then* your FXML sets the width and height properties by calls to `setWidth()` and `setHeight()`; however, by then it's too late because the drawing already occurred outside the bounds of the canvas. Subclassing canvas is simply the wrong approach here. (I'm in the process of writing an actual answer.)

Comment: @James_D found the problem, the FXML ID didn't match to the one in the controller 
Thank YOU FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: Well, that's another problem, but it's not the cause of the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to draw on the canvas *before* you set the width and height. Because your `Canvas` subclass implicitly invokes the default `Canvas` constructor, which sets the width and height to zero, then in the constructor you perform the drawing. Since this drawing happens outside the bounds of the canvas, nothing appears. The `width` and `height` attributes in the FXML cause the `setWidth()` and `setHeight()` methods to be invoked, but of course this happens *after* the constructor call is complete, by which time it is too late.

A "quick fix" is to allow the width and height to be passed to your constructor, so you can pass them on to the `Canvas` constructor:

```
public class HeightMapDisplayer extends Canvas {

    public HeightMapDisplayer(
            @NamedArg("width") double width,
            @NamedArg("height") double height) {

        super(width, height);
        GraphicsContext gc = this.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(Color.RED);
        gc.fillOval(10,10,40,40);
    }
}
```

---

However, it is generally a bad idea to subclass JavaFX node classes (other than those specifically written with the intention of subclassing them, such as `Cell`s). A much better approach is to use a MVC approach: define a model class encapsulating the data you want to represent on the canvas, define a controller to do the drawing, and just use a plain `Canvas`.

E.g. the (mock) model class might look like

```
public class HeightMap {

    // data you need here...
    private int offset ;
    private int size ;

    public int getOffset() {
        return offset;
    }
    public void setOffset(int offset) {
        this.offset = offset;
    }
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

}
```

with a controller class

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class HeightMapController {

    private final Canvas view ;
    private HeightMap model ;

    public HeightMapController(Canvas view) {
        this.view = view ;
    }

    public void setModel(HeightMap model) {
        this.model = model ;
        GraphicsContext gc = view.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(Color.RED);
        gc.fillOval(model.getOffset(), model.getOffset(), model.getSize(), model.getSize());
    }

}
```

Here's an updated `MainWindowController`:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;

public class MainWindowController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Canvas heightMap;

    private HeightMapController heightMapController ;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        heightMapController = new HeightMapController(heightMap);
    }

    public void setHeightMapModel(HeightMap heightMapModel) {
        heightMapController.setModel(heightMapModel);
    }
}
```

and FXML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.canvas.MainWindowController">
    <left>
        <Canvas fx:id="heightMap"
            height="400" width="400" />
    </left>
</BorderPane>
```

and finally the code that assembles everything:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        MainWindowController controller = loader.getController();
        HeightMap heightMap = new HeightMap();
        heightMap.setOffset(10);
        heightMap.setSize(40);
        controller.setHeightMapModel(heightMap);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

There are other techniques that can make this a bit cleaner, e.g. using a controller factory to instantiate controllers with the model already present, or using a dependency injection framework to achieve the same thing, but this should give you the idea of the correct structure.